# Get any value from Cortana voice command result

Tags: win-universal-app, cortana

Is it posible to read any value from Cortana voice command?

For example, when I say:

> "Search {something} in my library"

I want to get the result from {something} in my app.

I found how to work with *PhraseList* and *PhraseTopic*, but in my case could be any word instead of some declared items or one topic.

Comment: Would it help to have an example? https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Samples/Cortana/Cortana.xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your VoiceCommands.xml you need:

```
<PhraseTopic Label="something" Scenario="Natural Language">
  <Subject> Natural Language </Subject>
</PhraseTopic>
```

In your App.xaml.cs you need:

```
     private string SemanticInterpretation(string interpretationKey, SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult)
    {
        return speechRecognitionResult.SemanticInterpretation.Properties[interpretationKey].FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

In the OnActivated Method (or wherever else you Handle the command)
you can read it out with:

```
switch (voiceCommandName)
       {
        case "something":
              string something = this.SemanticInterpretation("something", speechRecognitionResult);
```

something will be everything between search and in my library

Comment: I used your answer to answer a question I place a bounty on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106171/how-to-extract-the-argument-from-a-cortana-command-with-a-phrase-topic-activate. If you post an answer there I'll award you the bounty.